# PHP Mail: Page content to mail

Tags: php, email

I have a form that customers fill in with personal data and also makes choices regarding the service. So with the $_GET function I retrieve the information of that form, do some basic math and show all the information so the customer can preview the order and then hit "SEND" to confirm the job.

I need to send that Preview Order to me by mail but I don't know how to send all that. I know how to retrieve data from a form and then send it, but have no idea how to send those variables.

FORM

```
// I am omitting elements to make this shorter    
<select name="Amount">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>
```

PREVIEW ORDER

```
  $price = 5;  

    // I am omitting elements to make this shorter 
    // here I do some math     
    $Amount = $_GET['Amount']; 
        // check value and select appropriate item 
        if ($Amount== "1") { 
            $extra = "1"; 
            } 
        elseif ($Amount == "2") { 
            $extra = "2"; 
            } 
        elseif ($Amount == "3") { 
            $extra = "3";


// here is the order preview and this is what I need to email to myself
// the customer should look this preview and then HIT a confirm buttom to get this sent

<?php echo $Name;?><br>
<?php echo $Address;?><br>
<?php echo $E-mail;?><br>
<?php echo $Phone;?><br>
Your order: <?php echo $extra . " " . "products, for a total of" . " " . ($price * $extra); ?>
```

-------------------- FINAL VERSION --------------- THANKS to all of you guys!

I'll be only using 2 fields in order to shrink the code

// FORM -- The user entries his data

```
<form method="get" id="order" action="order-info.php">
<h1>Personal Info</h1>
<p>name: <input name="name" type="text" /></p>
<p>email: <input name="surname" type="text" /></p>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Continue">
</form>
```

//ORDER Preview -- Here the user can preview all of his data and product related choices before confirming the order

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
// get info personal
$Name = $_GET['name'];
$Email = $_GET['email'];
?>
// Now I echo the info
<h2><?php echo $Name . " " . $Email ; ?><br></h2>
<?php
  // here's where the magic is done thanks to Sheldon Ferns!
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['name'] = $Name;
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['email'] = $Email;

?>
// having stored all the info in a session I proceed to send it to the email function. That weird name is because I read you should avoid naming your email process file with predictable names like mail.php, this increases protection against spammers. 
<form  method ="POST" action = "xljkadf.php">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Confirm Order">
```

//MAIL PROCESS --

```
<?php  session_start();
 # Anti-header-injection - Use before mail() 
# By Victor Benincasa <vbenincasa(AT)gmail.com> 
foreach($_REQUEST as $fields => $value) if(eregi("TO:", $value) || eregi("CC:", $value) || eregi("CCO:", $value) || eregi("Content-Type", $value)) exit("ERROR: Code injection attempt denied! Please don't use the following sequences in your message: 'TO:', 'CC:', 'CCO:' or 'Content-Type'."); 

  $headers = 'From: Your Site <noreply@yoursite.com>' . "\n".
// in the next line what I do is to send a BCC to me as I want the customer to get a copy of the order without knowing my address  
$headers .= 'Bcc: Your site <yourmail@xxxx.com>' . "\r\n";



  $mailBody = "Order details: \n". 
                "Name: ".$_SESSION['customerInfo']['name'] . "\n".
                "Email: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['email'] . "\n";




// Next the mail function. The first arguments is the customer e-mail so he gets a copy of his order.
   mail($_SESSION['customerInfo']['Email'], "Order Info ", $mailBody, $headers);

   ?>
 // A redirect to a thank you page once the e-mail is sent.
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
window.location.href = "http://www.yoursite.com/thank-you.html";
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: hi, some inputs.. 1.under MAIL PROCESS - i dnt see any use of foreach($_REQUEST as $fields => $value) .... 
2. I suggest u use header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/thank-you.html'); exit(); after the mail() function instead of window.location.href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sent an email when the user clicks the **SEND** button from the preview page. But you do not know how to get the data in PHP that the customer is previewing; because Send does not submit a form. 
It this is what your problem is then, here's what you can do

When customer submits your, in the previewOrder php file you can save the information in a session variable.. eg

```
<?php
  session_start(); ?>
  //The php code you have already written.

  //Saving data in session
  <?php
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['Name'] = $Name;
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['Address'] = $Address;
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['Email'] = $Email;
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['Phone'] = $Phone;
  $_SESSION['customerInfo']['Extra'] = $Extra;
?>
```

Note that session_start() has to be at the beginning of the file.

Now, from the preview page when the user clicks SEND button, you have to direct the page to a file like sendOrder.php which should like something like this

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $mailBody = "Order Info: \n". 
              "Name: ".$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Name'] . "\n".
              "Address: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Address'] . "\n".
              "Email: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Email'] . "\n".
              "Phone: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Email'] . "\n".
              "Price: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Price'] . "\n".
              "Extra: " .$_SESSION['customerInfo']['Extra'] . "\n";

   mail('your@mail.com', 'Order Information', $mailBody);

?>
```

What you are doing here is reading values you have saved in the session in the preview. SESSIONS is one way you can make variables available across pages.

Hope this helps,

PS.I have not tested the code for syntax errors.Please correct them if any :)

Comment: Many thanks Sheldon!! I works like charm! I implemented your solution and pasted the final code above!! Thanks again buddy!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to know how to send some content in an email using php.
See the `mail` function in php. Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). The `message` argument can contain your content. Also go through the examples in the documentation, you'll get an idea of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a string like this (I'm omitting line breaks and extra formatting):

`$mystring = 'Name: '.$Name.', Address: '.$Address.', E-mail: '.$E-mail.', $Phone: '.$Phone;`

Then send it via `mail()`:

`mail('myaddress@php.com', 'My Subject', $mystring);`

Answer (score 0):

`$mailBody` will capture everything you echo'ed between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`.
`mail()` function will send the email to you.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php echo $Name;?><br>
<?php echo $Address;?><br>
<?php echo $E-mail;?><br>
<?php echo $Phone;?><br>
Your order: <?php echo $extra . " " . "products, for a total of" . " " . ($price * $extra); ?>
<?php $mailBody = ob_get_clean(); 

mail('your@mail.com', 'Mail Subject', $mailBody);

?>
```